# Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Report.jar\ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: deployment, jboss, jbossfuse

I am trying to deploy jar file in Jboss fsw, however deployment fails with following message

> POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Report.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Report.jar"
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.switchyard.as7.extension.deployment.SwitchYardConfigProcessor$JBossPropertyResolver.set(SwitchYardConfigProcessor.java:106)
>           at org.switchyard.as7.extension.deployment.SwitchYardConfigProcessor$JBossPropertyResolver.access$000(SwitchYardConfigProcessor.java:87)
>           at org.switchyard.as7.extension.deployment.SwitchYardConfigProcessor.deploy(SwitchYardConfigProcessor.java:60)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
>           ... 5 more
>
> 19:16:58,082 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 11) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Report.jar" was rolled back with the following failure message:
>   {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Report.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Report.jar\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Report.jar\"
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
>   19:16:58,089 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Report.jar (runtime-name: Report.jar) in 6ms

Comment: I rebuild jar and tried to deploy and this time error message is                                                                 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 21) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Report.jar" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Report.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Report.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"BIHReport.jar\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to avoid this issue. It seems the issue was with the switchyard project structure which I created. I just recreated the project and this time I didn't get deployment issue !!